# React state update during control change breaks OrbitControls from three

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, drei, react-three-drei

I am using react three with drei orbitControls and try to detect wether the camera is above or below zero, while moving the camera around. Currently I'm using onEnd listener to trigger my code in my ParentComponent. If I change a state of my parent component like so everything works as expected. Unfortunately if I start another change of orbit controls before ending another and change my parents state, orbit controls will break. E.g. I rotate the camera and hold down my left mouse button, than get below zero with my camera and the scroll with my mouse wheel at the same time, Orbit controls no longer works. This is especially painful when using touch. As soon as a second finger touches and I cross the ground orbit control breaks.

This is my Controls Component:

```
const Controls = forwardRef(({ handleCamera }, ref) => {
  const { gl, camera } = useThree();
  const controls = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getCamera() {
      return camera
    },
  }))

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      handleCamera(camera); 
  }

  return (
    <OrbitControls ref={controls}
      onEnd={(e) => handleChange(e)}
    />
  );
});

export default Controls;
```

And this is my parent:

```
function App() {  
  const handleCamera = (camera) => {
    setCameraBelowSurface(camera.position.y <= 0 ? true : false);
  };
  return
    <Canvas >
      <Suspense>
        <Controls
          ref={controlsRef}
          handleCamera={handleCamera}
        />          
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>    
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fortunatelly I found out a solution for this problem. I hope it is going to be helpful for someone.

First of all when you use state variable and change their value then component will re-render which causing this issue. So instead of state variables you need to just use ref.

```
 const isDragging = React.useRef(false);
```

Setting the current property of ref in 'onStart' and 'onEnd' events:

```
<OrbitControls
  onStart={() => {
    isDragging.current = true;
  }}
  onEnd={() => {
    isDragging.current = false;
  }}
  autoRotate={false}
  autoRotateSpeed={0.4}
/>
```